# How to regularly secure/backup Telegram Chats?

Tags: backup, chat, whatsapp

since Telegram offers the option to delete complete chats for both sides - is there any way to secure your data?

For example someone keeps harassing you through the Telegram chat, and later deletes either parts of it or the complete chat, so that you don't have access to it through your Telegram cloud - are there any apps which could back up regularly the chat?

Sorry, I'm a total noob regarding this topic

Answer (score 0):

See, telegram is based on cloud concept — which means they try to eliminate the need of backups. They do not have data stored locally on your device, rather they store it in the cloud. So, there is not any option for frequent backups. However, on Telegram for PC, there is an option for export chat. Go to Menu > Settings > Advanced >  Export to export chat. Just wait for the right moment, and when you think you have the evidence of harrasment, immediately export your chat.